# How do I check if a method exists for a particular type?

Tags: julia

**LATEST UPDATE:** Shep has provided an answer that updates this question to v1+.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @rickhg12s for pointing out that it appears I may have stumbled upon a bug. `method_exists(<, (MyType, MyType))` is returning `true` while `method_exists(isless, (MyType, MyType))` is returning `false`. I'm on v0.3.x but @rickhg12s is on the nightly build of v0.4, so I'll file an issue.

How do I check if a method exists for a particular type?

I thought I could do this using, for example:

```
method_exists(<, (Int, Int))
```

which will return `true` since the less than comparison is defined for two integers. However, when I define my own type:

```
type MyType; end
```

and then try:

```
method_exists(<, (MyType, MyType))
```

it returns `true`. But I thought that it would return `false`, since:

```
a = MyType()
a < a
```

throws an error since `<` is not defined for `MyType`. So how can I detect at run-time whether a method for a given type exists?

Comment: Interesting, `a < a` generates `ERROR: MethodError: ``isless`` has no method matching isless(::MyType, ::MyType)
 in < at operators.jl:32`.  And `method_exists(isless, (MyType, MyType))` generates `false`.

Comment: @rickhg12s Very interesting, many thanks. So perhaps I've stumbled on a bug. Are you on v0.4? I'm on v0.3.x, so I don't want to file an issue unless I can confirm that this is still a problem on v0.4.

Comment: Yep, I'm at the head of Github's master branch.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Great thanks. I've filed an issue.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Huh. Turns out that behaviour is expected (although the devs agreed it is definitely confusing at first glance). I've converted the response I got on the github issue into an answer below. Cheers and thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunate news to me too.  8-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that `method_exists` *is* (currently) the best way to check whether a method exists for a particular type, but one needs to be very careful. My example above just happened to stumble upon some slightly confusing (but internally consistent) behaviour in Julia's inner workings. Read on if you're still interested.

@rickhg12s pointed out in the comments to the question that `method_exists(<, (MyType, MyType))` is returning `true` while `method_exists(isless, (MyType, MyType))` is returning `false`.

Sounds like a bug right? I filed [an issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/11385#issuecomment-104332878) and the julia devs confirmed that the behaviour observed, while admittedly confusing, is internally consistent.

`<` and `isless` are two different methods. Importantly, `<` has default behaviour for the case where no explicit method for `<` has been defined. That behaviour is to pass the arguments on to the `isless` function. The consequence of this behaviour is that `<` is implicitly defined for *every* type, even brand new ones that have just been created. So `method_exists(<, (MyType, MyType))` *should* return `true`. `isless` on the other hand, is the "lowest" in the chain - there is no other function it can pass things onto, so if `isless` has not been explicitly extended to the new type, Julia returns an error if you try to use it, and `method_exists(isless, (MyType, MyType))` will correctly return `false`.

Now that it has been pointed out to me, I can see the logic behind this. But the implication is that users of `method_exists` need to be careful that they're applying it to the function that is "lowest" in the chain.

Comment: Is there a function like method_exists that also checks for the return-type of the function? like `method_exists(name, args, return_type)`

Comment: @Nozdrum Not that I'm aware of, and such a function would be difficult to write, since some Julia functions have multiple return types. The only way I am aware of to extract such information is via [@code_warntype](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/#code-warntype) which is good for static analysis, but would be quite tricky to use dynamically at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to Base functions you can use [hasmethod](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.hasmethod).

```
hasmethod(<, Tuple{Int, Int}) # true

abstract type MyType end

hasmethod(isless, Tuple{MyType, MyType}) # false
```